# Repeat cells in a cell array - Matlab

Tags: matlab, duplicates, cell

I have that cell array:

```
Names={'L','A','C'}
```

And I need to repeat cells to stay whit this:

```
Names2={'L','L','L','L','A','A','A','A','C','C','C','C'}
```

How can I do it in a easy way?

Thank you :)

Comment: What language/program do you use?

Comment: Matlab, sorry. Thanks

Comment: @LiliaJorge please don't re-post an identical question if yours was already closed (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992087/repeat-cells-in-a-cell-array). The answer you got below was directly in the link I posted (and Natan has re-posted above) including more options. If you thought your question should have not been closed then you should comment on that question making your case.

Comment: and btw. please accept answers which solved your problem to indicate the system that the problem is solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ind = kron([1,2,3],ones(1,4));
Names2 = Names(ind);
```

The above code uses [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html). If you don't like it,

```
ind = repmat([1,2,3], 4, 1);
ind = reshape(ind, 1, []);
```

Comment: this will help me a lot. thank you